# Cordova debug.apk works fine, but signed version crashes

Tags: android, cordova, release, sign

I tested my debug.apk on several devices, and it worked.
I released it using

```
cordova build android --release
```

Afterwards, I signed it with

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore example.keystore example.apk example

jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs example.apk

zipalign -v 4 example.apk example_01.apk
```

The signed version can be installed, but as soon as I open the app, it crashes.
Is anyone else having the same problem?
If you need more specific information, please let me know

Greetings

Comment: Did you try to sign it in Android Studio ? (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I am running into the same problem

Comment: Same issue here.. any solution?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall unsigned apk before installing signed apk?